# Convert pandas.core.series.Series to Date (Year)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to convert a Series to a Date Format.
The column I'm trying to convert is `Year` so I can filter my daframe per year and then group by country, etc.

| Country | Year |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 2018 |
| USA | 2019 |
| CAD | 2018 |
| ARG | 2018 |
| ARG | 2017 |

I've tried multiple options (which I'll list below) and it always returns a "Series" type. I know this is a basic question but nothing I've tried has worked so far and I feel like it's right in front of me and I'm just not seeing it.

Option 1:

```
World['Year']=pd.to_datetime(World['Year'])
type((World['Year']))

Output= pandas.core.series.Series
```

Option 2

```
World['Year']=pd.to_datetime(World['Year'], format='%Y')
#Didn't work either
```

Option 3

```
World['Year']=pd.to_datetime(World['Year'], format='%Y').dt.date
```

I also thought about converting it to numeric so I can filter the data but I'm not sure that's the best idea. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: "*so I can filter my daframe per year*" - if your "year" column is of dtype integer, you don't have to convert anything to do that. Also, a date would require month and day, which you don't seem to have and also don't need for filtering/grouping by year.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert Series to Date format but what you can do is convert **the datatype** of Series to Date format. To check the datatype of a Series use World['Year'].dtype

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean how to convert it to `datetime64`

based on your option2, we can use `:=` operator

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country' : "USA,USA,CAD,ARG,ARG".split(","),
    'Year' : ["2018","2019","2018","2018","2017"]
})
print(df)
df["Year"] = (temp:=pd.to_datetime(df['Year'],format="%Y"))
print(df.dtypes)
```

this way we can got the `datetime64[ns]`